# get all document from all folder and subfolder from document library sharepoint 2010

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query

I want to retrieve all documents from folder to it's subfolder and so on using client object model.Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If tou would like to retrive only files you should add following line to the VbPatel solution.

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Lookup'>0</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

Comment: this is great but it does not retrieve the documents that are under folders and sub folders...

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution

```
  ClientContext clientContext =
        new ClientContext("http://Servername/");
        List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml =
            @"<View Scope='Recursive' />";

        ClientOM.ListItemCollection listItems =
            sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(listItems);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var item in listItems)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify a library's root folder using `SPList.Rootfolder` property and corresponding subfolders could be accessed using `SPList.Rootfolder.SubFolders[index]`

Please check this answer for more details and sample code - [How to move an item from custom list root location to sub folder programmatically?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32214/how-to-move-an-item-from-custom-list-root-location-to-sub-folder-programmaticall/32224#32224)

Comment: Hi deepu, thax for reply.I want to do this using client object model not object model.
And also it's not for only subfolder i want all document form subfolder's subfolder and so on.I think there is some recursive caml query which give all document collection.

Answer (score -2):

```
ClientContext clientContext =
new ClientContext("http://Servername/");
List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml =
@"<View Scope='Recursive' />";

ClientOM.ListItemCollection listItems =
sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in listItems)
{
}
```

Comment: -1 This appears to be an exact duplicate of the accepted answer. If it isn't, please explain what the differences are, and why they're important.