# How to get folder structure using csom?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to have all folder name which is present in my library and the folder structure is like this:

```
Folder 1
    Sub Folder 1.1
            Sub Folder 1.1.1
    Sub Folder 1.2

Folder 2
    Sub Folder 2.1
            Sub Folder 2.1.1

Folder 3
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

D,

I'll refer you to an existing answer: [get all document from all folder and subfolder from document library sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32556/get-all-document-from-all-folder-and-subfolder-from-document-library-sharepoint)

In short, you can do a simple CamlQuery against the list for all items with FSObjType (Lookup) value of "1" but ensure you include the Scope="Recursive" attribute as part of the  element.  Once you have the values returned, you can build up your structure based on the URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After checking this I will get back to you
Thank you for your time

Comment: I need all the folder names not the documents in it. So that is not working for me.